# settext() for textview inside Fragment is not changing the textview

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fragments, textview, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment activity that creates several fragments for a viewpager.  The first fragment I'm making is a port from previously being an activity.  Before the activity's onCreate method set a textview based on some prior user input.

However now that this is a fragment the same code in onCreateView is ignoring the setText() method and only ever shows the default XML layout text inside the UI elements.

I've seen other people with this issue and yet not found it to be resolved.  How can I setText for a textview in a fragment, the way it used to work for onCreate in an activity?

Thanks.

edit:  The text I'm trying to set comes in through an intent when the host FragmentActivity (which makes the fragments) is created.  So

```
Activity A + String str --> 
creates FragmentActivity (gets str from intent).  --> 
Fragment 1, textView TV, TV.sestText(str);
```

If you need to see code, its from this example:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Where inside Tab1Fragment, I've added a textview to the XML file, and I'm trying to call setText inside the onCreateView method in Tab1Frag.

If I recall, it goes something like this...

```
public RelativeLayout onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    if (container == null) {           
        return null;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, null);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag1_title);  
title.setText("Success!");

return (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);

}
```

Comment: Show us **your** Tab1Fragment code, it has clearly changed from the tutorial.

Comment: Added to edit above.  Have you ever worked with fragments before?

Comment: Yes I have. Just post your `onCreateView()` method, the tutorial's is very basic - it doesn't even work with the layout, just returns the inflated view.

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but its a common problem 
googling "android fragment settext"  or "fragment textview settext".  Other have the same problem and posted their code.  

All I did was add a textview to the XML and try calling settext within onCreate like you would with an activity.  Which as you know works.   But the fact that this is a fragment is the issue.  
Take an activity where you settext in oncreate and the code is the same.  That's what I'm saying.

Comment: I set all my UI elements and modify them in `onCreateView()`, it's the easiest. Also, have a look at the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). `onCreate()` then `onCreateView()` is called.

Comment: I've added some code if it helps.  Mine was in onCreateView, and still has this problem.

Comment: Make it return your `view` variable instead. You're reinflating. Also, I don't see a need for the explicit return of the Type `RelativeLayout`, returning the type `View` is the proper override.

Comment: Brilliant.  That did the trick, except I did have to cast the type.  Just curious, what do you mean by the proper 'override'?

Comment: Usually you just Return `View`. Otherwise you're overloading the method (creating a new method signature). However, in this case it's ok just because `RelativeLayout` is a `View` subclass.